# Smooth representation of profinite group as a limit

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory, abelian-categories, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group. As is well-known, we may write $G = \operatorname{lim} G/N$ for $N$ family of normal open compact subgroups of $G$ (which is a cofiltered limit, and we may index it by $\mathbb{N}$). For any pair of such subgroups $N$ and $M$ such that $N \subseteq M$, there is a projection $\pi_{NM} \colon G/N \to G/M$, which induces a functor $\operatorname{Ind}_{G/N}^{G/M} \colon \operatorname{Rep}(G/N) \to \operatorname{Rep}(G/M)$.

This defines a diagram in the category of tensor categories (with maybe well-behaved functors). Is $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ the limit of this diagram?

Comment: Surely it is with a suitable definition of a representation of a profinite group (which is not just a group!). Which definition are you working with?

Comment: I began thinking about smooth or continuous representations (in which case the representation would be trivial for some $N$), but this works for any representation of $G$, and we have the inclusion from special representations to any representation, then the natural candidate should maybe (strangely enough) the category of all representations

Comment: What is the field over which your representations are taken? If it's the complexes, then all (finite-dimensional) representations of profinite groups have finite image, so your statement should hold.

Comment: I'm taking finite dimensional representations over the complexes, because, as you said, continuity or smoothness implies finite-dimensional image.